# Accessing current authenticated user with ASP.net core 3 using JWT authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, jwt

I have a basic app where it uses JWT for authentication. Now my app is partially functional as it can already validate user and return JWT token for the client side to consume.

So if a user is already logged in, I need to access the details of that user so I tried doing this one.

JWT auth configuration:

```
services.AddAuthentication(option =>
            {
                option.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                option.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(option =>
            {
                option.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                option.SaveToken = true;
                option.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["ApplicationSettings:SecretKey"])
                    ),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
```

I inject `HttpContextAccessor` in Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

add `app.useAuthentication()` in Configure method as well.

Then use it to my controller

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
public UserController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContext)
{         
   _httpContext = httpContext;
}
```

When I try to access an endpoint where I display the current user it returns this one.

```
{"claims":[],"identities":[{"authenticationType":null,"isAuthenticated":false,"actor":null,"bootstrapContext":null,"claims":[],"label":null,"name":null,"nameClaimType":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name","roleClaimType":"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"}],"identity":{"name":null,"authenticationType":null,"isAuthenticated":false}}
```

I read some solution that I modify `launchSettings.json` and set windowsAuthentication: true and anonymousAuthentication: false, but it is not applicable in this case since I'm not using Windows Authentication.

Comment: How are you trying to read the user information? Using the exposed User object that any controller has?

Comment: How are you building the JWT token? You need to make sure you're adding the claim(s) when doing so.

Comment: Also, make sure the controller (or controller action) where you're accessing the context has the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: @MattU yeah I just realized I need to annotate the method with [Authorize] in order to access the current user